# How can I have autocomplete using external libraries in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, editor

I am using the ActionSherlockBar in my project and I realized that eclipse can't autocomplete (ctrl+space) methods like "OnOptionsItemSelected()"...

Is it possible to enable it?

Comment: What language is this library for? Is that syntactically valid where you're trying to complete it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say that! ActionSherlockBar is an external library for  android (java) and yes... I was typing it in the right place.

Comment: That looks like the name of a constructor. Was it preceded by a "new"?

Comment: Nope! The signature of the method is  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}